# Clearcase Command to view branches created by a specific user

Tags: clearcase

What is the command to get the list of branches created by a specific user in Clearcase ?
Moreover, is there a command to get the list of branches by name using regular expressions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for regular expression.

You can list branches with a [`cleartool lstype -fmt "%n %u\n" -kind brtype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm?resultof=%22lstype%22), but you would still need to parse the result to get the one created by you.

Using the [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) options, you can display the creator and name of the branch, for you to parse.